# The problem of nested routes not loading in React Router version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, loadable-component

When I send a **quoteId** and try to open a comment for it, the **Comments** component does not load.
I tried to do this using a loadable component, but it still didn't work
I don't have any errors in my console, there are only a few warnings as follows:

*You rendered descendant  (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/quotes/q1" (under ) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.
Please change the parent  to .*

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component';
// const Comments = loadable(() => import('../components/comments/Comments'));

const QuoteDetail = () =>
{
    const params = useParams();
    const quote = DUMMY_QUOTES.find(item => item.id === params.quoteId);

    const btnComment =
        <div className='centered'>
            <Link className='btn--flat' to={`/quotes/${params.quoteId}/comments`}>Load Comments</Link>  
        </div>
        
    return (
        <>
            <HighlightedQuote text={quote.text} author={quote.author} />

            <Routes>
                <Route path={`/quotes/${params.quoteId}`} element={btnComment} />
                <Route path={`/quotes/${params.quoteId}/comments`} element={<Comments />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import AllQuotes from "./pages/AllQuotes";
import QuoteDetail from "./pages/QuoteDetail";
import NewQuote from "./pages/NewQuote";
import Layout from "./components/layout/Layout";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";

const App = () =>
{
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<AllQuotes />} />
                <Route path="/quotes" element={<AllQuotes />} />
                <Route path="/quotes/:quoteId" element={<QuoteDetail />} />
                <Route path="/new-quote" element={<NewQuote />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```